# Reordering targets for collectionViewCells in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to implement a behavior in my collectionViewCell.

The Cell checks whether there is an image for that cell, or not.
If there is an image you will get a cross symbol (for deleting)
If there is no image you will get a plus symbol (for adding)

Whenever you click on a plussymbol a method is triggered, whenever a cross symbol is clicked, another method will trigger.

See my

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath {
    if let imageId = imageIds[indexPath.row] as? String {

    if let imageData = imageForId[imageId]{

                collectionCell.collectionViewImage.image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                collectionCell.collectionViewButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "kreuzzeichen.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                 collectionCell.collectionViewButton!.addTarget(self, action: "showDeleteAlert:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            }

        }
    } else{

        collectionCell.collectionViewButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pluszeichen.png"), forState: .Normal)
        collectionCell.collectionViewImage.image = nil
        collectionCell.collectionViewButton.removeTarget(self, action: "showDeleteAlert:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        collectionCell.collectionViewButton!.addTarget(self, action: "pickImage", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    }

}
```

However deleting the one of the images, makes the `collectionView` reorder it cells. The symbols are swapped if necessary, but the targets aren't.

**Is there a way to refresh this?**

I have tried to check whether:

```
collectionCell.collectionViewImage.setImage == UIImage(named:"kreuzzeichen.png")
```

But it wouldn't compare those, so my code afterwords didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Remove the `pickImage` target too in the if condition

```
if let imageData = imageForId[imageId]{

         collectionCell.collectionViewImage.image = UIImage(data:imageData)
         collectionCell.collectionViewButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "kreuzzeichen.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
         collectionCell.collectionViewButton!.addTarget(self, action: "showDeleteAlert:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
         collectionCell.collectionViewButton.removeTarget(self, action: "pickImage:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    }
     else {
        collectionCell.collectionViewButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pluszeichen.png"), forState: .Normal)
        collectionCell.collectionViewImage.image = nil
        collectionCell.collectionViewButton.removeTarget(self, action: "showDeleteAlert:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        collectionCell.collectionViewButton!.addTarget(self, action: "pickImage", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I also had to remove the target, before adding the new one. and there is a ":" after your pickImage. But finally it works!